# Javascript convert object in string to object literal

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm parsing an API in NodeJS that returns this data, as a string:

```
{
    "query": {
        "count": 1,
        "created": "2013-12-09T08:05:21Z",
        "lang": "en-US",
        "results": {
            "rate": {
                "id": "GBPEUR",
                "Name": "GBP to EUR",
                "Rate": "1.1938",
                "Date": "12/9/2013",
                "Time": "3:05am",
                "Ask": "1.194",
                "Bid": "1.1936"
            }
        }
    }
```

}

I'd like to convert this into a javascript Object so that I can parse it like `var rate = obj.query.results.rate.Rate`.

I've tried using Node's [QueryString](http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) Parse() but this doesn't work as expected, and `eval()` doesn't work either. How can I achieve this (obviously preferably without using `eval()`)?

Comment: Hint: that happens to be valid JSON.

Comment: @user2864740 Well now I feel dumb! Ta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use JSON.parse

```
JSON.parse(json_string)
```

Comment: That assumes that the String is a **valid** JSON. Which may or may not be the case. Wouldn't some sanitation be advisable?

Comment: The posted data is valid JSON, I already linted it before answering

Comment: I know that the example data is a valid JSON, I am saying that it may not be in all cases, depending on which API of which Node module is being called. For all you know - it's a string that kinda looks like an object. Basically - that there is a bug and one would be wise to do some defensive programming (if that is at all possible). Just trying to add something to an already fine answer.

Comment: In that case JSON.parse just fails. If you're expecting JSON, there's no need to write something fancy to see if it's JSON

Comment: Personally I'd use domains if it was an issue, but it rarely is.